# How to perform cross join on different vertices in Gremlin/Tinkerpop

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I am new in the graph database. It might be a very basic question but any help is really appreciated.
I am using Gremlin/Tinkerpop 3 to query a graph stored in TitanDB.

Following is my data set.

```
User            |  associated_ids
---------------------------------
    A           | [ 1, 2 ]
    B           | [ 3, 4 ]
    c           | [ 5 ]
    D           | [ 4, 2 ]
```

Now want to get all the user's group who are linked with each other with any of the associated_id.
Here [A] & [D] is directly linked as both have common entity [2] and [B] & [D] is directly linked as both have common entity [4].
So indirectly [A], [B] & [D] are linked.

**Expected result something like.**

```
    Users       |  associated_ids
    ----------------------------
    A,B,D       | [ 1, 2 ,3, 4]
    c           | [ 5 ]
```

Following are the steps I have performed to generate the graph.

```
    a = graph.addVertex(label, "person", "user", "A")
    b = graph.addVertex(label, "person", "user", "B")
    c = graph.addVertex(label, "person", "user", "C")
    d = graph.addVertex(label, "person", "user", "D")

    one = graph.addVertex('rec_id')
    one.property('ids', '1')

    two = graph.addVertex('rec_id')
    two.property('ids', '2')

    three = graph.addVertex('rec_id')
    three.property('ids', '3')

    four = graph.addVertex('rec_id')
    four.property('ids', '4')

    five = graph.addVertex('rec_id')
    five.property('ids', '5')

    a.addEdge('part_of',one)
    a.addEdge('part_of',two)
    b.addEdge('part_of', three)
    b.addEdge('part_of',four)
    c.addEdge('part_of',five)
    d.addEdge('part_of',four)
    d.addEdge('part_of',two)
```

**Now wanted to know how can I get all the users who are associated with each other via any of the `rec_id`.**

**What would be the Gremlin query to get the desired output?**

Also please let me know if I need to do any change in my graph structure to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're basically looking for, are [connected components](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#connected-components).

```
gremlin> g.V().
           emit(cyclicPath().or().not(both())).
             repeat(both()).
             until(cyclicPath()).
           aggregate("p").by(path()).cap("p").
           unfold().limit(local, 1).dedup().
           map(__.as("v").select("p").unfold().
                  filter(unfold().where(eq("v"))).
                  unfold().dedup().order().by(id).fold()).dedup().
           project("Users","associated_ids").
             by(unfold().hasLabel("person").values("user").fold()).
             by(unfold().hasLabel("rec_id").values("ids").fold())
==>[Users:[A,B,D],associated_ids:[1,2,3,4]]
==>[Users:[C],associated_ids:[5]]
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what exactly I am looking for. But It is bit slow even with the small data set. Is it efficient for big data?

Comment: Since it's a full scan, you'd have to run it in OLAP (the query will need a few tweaks to work in OLAP). At this point you can't expect realtime results; if you need (near) realtime results, run the OLAP job frequently and store its result in the graph or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the answer you want:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('rec_id','ids','1').
......1>   in().aggregate('s').
......2>   repeat(out().in().where(without('s')).aggregate('s')).
......3>   cap('s').unfold().valueMap()
==>[user:[A]]
==>[user:[D]]
==>[user:[B]]
gremlin> g.V().has('rec_id','ids','5').
......1>   in().aggregate('s').
......2>   repeat(out().in().where(without('s')).aggregate('s')).
......3>   cap('s').unfold().valueMap()
==>[user:[C]]
```

So you basically hold your group of user vertices in "s" as you traverse the graph. The line marked "1>" shows where you get the initial users who are in the "rec_id" you requested. In line "2>" you recursively traverse away from those users and find their "rec_ids" and ignore any users you've already encountered which are stored in "s". The final line at "3>" extracts the "s" side-effect from the traversal and for convenience, expands that list of vertices and runs a `valueMap()` on it so we nicely see the "user" properties.